# Creating a for loop to take in numbered user inputs

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have a javascript program that will on click create additional text boxes for users to input data.

So what it does is

```
<input type="text" id="uTitle1" />
```

User clicks to add another box and it creates this

```
<input type="text" id="uTitle2" />
```

etc. etc.

I now need to actually get those inputs and put them into some sort of list so that I can then run a for loop to print them onto a new page using document.write()

I cannot seem to figure the correct way to do this

I have tried

t1 is my iterator

```
function loopThroughInputs(input){
    var storedList = [];

    for (i = 0; i < t1; i++){
      var currentVar = document.getElementById(input + (i + 1));
      storedList.push(currentVar)
    };
}
```

Comment: `getElementFromId` should be `getElementById`.

Comment: Do you want to get the inputs, or their values? If you want the values, use `currentVar.value`.

Comment: Your IDs start from 1, not 0.

Comment: Whoops sorry I was in python mode there I'm learning both atm.

I just need the values in them so that I can print them. Thanks for the help so far

Comment: Give all the inputs the same class. Then use `document.getElementsByClassName()` or `document.querySelectorAll()` and loop over that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two separate methods being demonstrated here.

The first uses a simple class on all of your inputs and simply loops through them.

The second adds a data attribute to the button and to each input field. This method allows you to use a data attribute to store the field that you want to get assuming there are groups of them.

The function that I created just passes a selector to loop through.

```js
function loopThroughInputs(selector){
    let inputs = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    let storedList = [];
    
    inputs.forEach((i)=>{
      storedList.push(i.value)
    });
    
    return storedList;
}

document.querySelector(".btn-getByGeneric").addEventListener("click",() => {
  console.log(loopThroughInputs(".input"))
});

document.querySelector(".btn-getByField").addEventListener("click",(e) => {
  console.log(loopThroughInputs("input[data-field='" + e.target.dataset.field + "']"))
});
```

```html
<input data-field="uTitle" type="text" class="input" />
<input data-field="uTitle" type="text" class="input" />
<input data-field="uTitle" type="text" class="input" />
<hr>
<button class="btn-getByGeneric">get by generic class</button>
<button class="btn-getByField" data-field="uTitle">get by field</button>
```

Comment: I thank you for showing me these methods they work perfectly for what im trying to accomplish.